# OpenGL override scene transparency

Tags: java, opengl

I'm using GL11 in Java, and the current issue I'm facing is blending. I'm making a simple fade-out animation, and as shown in the image, the borders of the rectangle are darker because they've drawn over the background. How can I override an entire scene to be at one transparency level? Apologies if this doesn't make sense, I'm new to OpenGL.

My code:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
DrawUserInterface(x, y); // Simple vertex rectangles
```

[image: The borders are darker than the background at low-alpha]

Comment: Adjust the scale of the rectangle to fill out the entire visible area, and change the alpha value of the vertex colors to match the fading animation's current transparency value. (It's difficult to give a more precise answer, you could edit the post and show how `DrawUserInterface()` draws the rectangles.)

Comment: You could draw the UI, then draw the background with increasing alpha. You could draw the UI to a texture and draw the texture with alpha (but not in OpenGL 1.1)